# Change background of the thumb of Trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

Is any way to change the background of the thumb of Trackbar? I use C# winform.

Only the background of the Trackbar can be changed, so how can I change or set something in the thumb?

Any answer appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7974/A-variation-on-the-default-TrackBar

And add the Picture of it to let user choose:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set Image of Trackbar's thumb
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Description("Set the picture of the thumb")]
    [Category("Image")]
    public Image Picture
    {
        set
        {
            myPic = value;
        }
        get { return myPic; }
    }
```

And use TextureBrush to let the picture People shoose be an ImageBrush:

```
 TextureBrush newBrush = new TextureBrush(myPic);
 if (myPic != null)
 {
      g.FillRegion(newBrush, new Region(PaintPath));
      newBrush.Dispose();
 }
 else
 {
      g.FillRegion(bgBrush, new Region(PaintPath));
      bgBrush.Dispose();
 }
```

There is only one problem that the imagebrush is tile style,

if I let it not a tile style, it may resolve my questrion.